# OpenCV Android : bitMapToMat function is crashing app

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv

I am trying to set up an android app that can perform some image processing on a loaded image. I have added the android OpenCV package to the app and this is my main activity code. I am using the latest 4.6.0 opencv android package.

The line

```
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
```

crashes the app

What am I missing here?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var select : Button
    lateinit var camera : Button
    lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    lateinit var mat : Mat
    val SELECT_CODE = 100


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("LOADED", "Success")
        } else {
            Log.d("LOADED", "err")
        }

        camera = findViewById(R.id.camera)
        select = findViewById(R.id.select)
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        select.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    intent.type = "image/*"
                    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
                }
    }

    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            if(data != null) {
                val selectedPhotoUri = data.data
                try {
                    selectedPhotoUri?.let {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                this.contentResolver,
                                selectedPhotoUri
                            )
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                        } else {
                            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                        }
                    }
                    mat = Mat()
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
                } catch (e : java.lang.Exception) {
                    Log.d("EXCEPTION", "Exception was hit")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some other questions told me to make sure manager is loaded before trying out open cv code but this is also not working as it says "module not loaded" on both physical device and emulator
I have already tried doing this

```
private val mLoaderCallback: BaseLoaderCallback = object : BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    override fun onManagerConnected(status: Int) {
        if (status == SUCCESS) {
            Log.i("OPENCV", "OpenCV loaded successfully")
            select.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                resultLauncher.launch(intent)
            }
        } else {
            super.onManagerConnected(status)
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback)
}
```

Comment: If you can share the log, a better solution can be provided.

Comment: OpenCV 3.0 was released in summer of 2015. Might be a good idea to move on to something more recent...

Comment: I am actually not using opencv 3.0. It was one of my trials to make it work. I am actually using the latest 4.6.0 version

Comment: [Edit] your question and provide that information there. It's relevant.